# PHP Insert multiple records into MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, multirow

I have some code for simultaneously inserting several records  in MySQL.
Here is the form and the request to insert into the database.

So everything works fine, but when I try to add to the query and the current date, for example. Then, when I send the request, I get the following error:

For a week now I'm suffering: what could be the cause of the error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your code  for what you have done so far and what is the error you are getting? It would be better if you can give your table definition as well.

Comment: You said: "following error" but do not show the error. What error did you get?